# Iterate through a list of ordered pairs

Tags: list, for-loop, indexing

Say I have
list = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

I can iterate through the list by writing "for i in list:"

How then can I break down each pair and assign each value to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `i` is iterable as it will contains a tuple as following,

```
a=i[0] #variable a will get first value of tuple
b=i[1] #variable b will get second value of tuple
```

the overall code will look like this,

```
list1=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
for i in list1:
    a=i[0]
    b=i[1]
    print(a,b)
```

You can also use another for loop to iterate through the `i`